# SSRS report is empty

Tags: reporting-services

I'm starting to learn Reporting Services. I did my first report that uses a parameterised stored procedure as a data source. Unfortunately even though the procedure works when called from Management Studio, the report comes up empty. The parameter prompt is there and I entered the value that should work. Is there a way to see what's passed to the SQL server (I'm using VS 2012 PRO with SQL Server 2012 Express, So I don't have the SQL Profiler...)? Is there a way to display errors?

Comment: Did you already try previewing the query result of your DataSet in the report editor?

Comment: Add a text box above all the tables and set it to something like "Look At ME". If it prints but your other controls do not render then you are not getting data sent to your report.

Comment: You can also use the TOOLS|SQL Server Profiler -> Start New Trace in SQL Studio to show all commands being processed on that instance. Please not if you have ssrs on the same box you probably want to select the Events tab and select the Column Filter Button and select the "Login Filter" node then select the LIKE textbox to be the username you are testing with.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Filburt, I did try the preview in Query Designer and it worked. Irb, the headers render so the recordset returns empty. I don't have the Server profiler, because as I mentionned I'm running SQL 2012 Express, and the Express version doesn't come with a profiler.

Answer (score 0):

OK I finally figured it out. The stored proc. accepted an optional parameter:

```
@DealID varchar(15) = ''
```

I was testing it in the where clause like so:

```
WHERE (@DealID='') OR  (SA.Deal_ID = @DealID)
```

In the parameter settings of the dataset I specified a default value of "" and set it to accept null values and set it's visibility to hidden.

Turns out that even though there was a default value specified, the @DealID parameter was getting null in it. I only realised it when I commented out the WHERE clause and I finally got the data on the report. I solved it by modifying the WHERE like so:

```
WHERE (@DealID='' or @DealID is null) OR  (SA.Deal_ID = @DealID)
```